# Hive table taking decimal value as NULL

Tags: hive

I am  facing strange issue.I tried with tab delimiter both in file and in table definition and comma as well.

But in both cases it reads the decimal values as NULL.But when I define this fields as INT it works fine.

Sample data with comma delimited values:
1,22.334
2,445.322
3,999.233

defined this table as

create table x(ID INT,SAL DECIMAL(3,3)) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' location '\tmp\data\'

similarly for comma delimited file

create table x(ID INT,SAL DECIMAL(3,3)) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' location '\tmp\data\'

But in both cases it is reading decimal values as NULL?what is the issue

Comment: Why is there space between your 22.342 and 2 in your below example? 1,22.334 2

Comment: Just map these formatted values as `String`, then use SQL to remove the shitty thousand-separators and cast to the target numerical type e.g. `Decimal(15,3)`.

Comment: @ Espanta  actually it is not spaces....while posting this data it took different records on same line. it is like   rec1=1,22.334  rec2=2,445.322   rec3=3,999.233.All these records are on new lines

Comment: @Samson    Yes this is an alternative approach.But why this approach is failing?Was curious to know why hive is not able to parse these decimal values,either tab delimited or comma.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is Decimal datatype doesn't not accept comma in data.
Second problem is you have to increase the decimal(3,3) to minimum decimal(7,3) for the sample data provided.
As decimal (3,3) cannot hold any of 3 values.

As your raw data contains comma in data, 
You have to load the into table with all columns as string datatype .
Later use regular expression to remove the comma in data and load into second level hive table with decimal datatype.

Comment: Thanks for answering.I have tried same data in tab delimited format as well.But same issue.My sample data have maximum 3 digits after decimal.So I guess it should work and anyways even if it is more it will get rounded off or truncated?

Comment: DECIMAL implies **fixed scale/precision, exact computations**. Do you want your bank to truncate your savings account?!?

Comment: yes you are correct .When I increased the precision it is parsed correctly.But I am wondering although my data is 22.444 why it requires precision of DECIMAL(6,3) ? when I reduce the precision to 4,3 it is again NULL

Comment: @Gourav Decimal (6,3) means, it can accommodate total 6 digits in number and maximum 3 out of them after precision.
When you use decimal(4,3), it means Maximum total number of digits in number should not exceed 4  and maximum digits after precision should be maximum 3 in that 4 only.
22.444 has total 5 digits and 3 after precision in those 5. So minimum datatype required for this is decimal(5,3)